# Revmob iOS fullscreen ad error

Tags: ios, revmob

When I try to test the fullscreen ad on `iOS` simulator, the ad loads perfectly, but when I click it I get this error and the ad closes so I am not getting any clicks:

> [RevMob] Error opening the store: The operation couldn't be completed.
>   (Error while redirecting to the store (403) error -1.)

Comment: Did you try this on an device. I haven't used Revmob but from the error it looks like it's trying to open the Apple App Store which is not available on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the simulator doesn't contain the App Store app. Try to run it on a device.

Comment: It still happens on a device. User clicks ad, ad closes, and nothing happens.